# angular-chart does not show the series at the top like documentation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

`angular-chart.js` has a bar-chart example is [here](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). From here I used that `js` and `markup` code with some modification like this.

**html**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
                <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
                  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" >
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);
app.controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.labels = ['PDM', 'R&D', 'SN', 'MB'];
      $scope.series = ['Late', 'NoLate'];

      $scope.data = [
        [10,2,1,2],
        [5,3,2,4]
      ];
}]);
```

for more check https://plnkr.co/edit/jIqY72Lg4YvkMNbmawyC?p=preview

But the problem is my code doesn't show like with the marked option.
[image]

What I do wrong or any update I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure under options,

```
$scope.options = {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top'
    }
  };
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MAiPwoVIZ5QrUfOlfyEr?p=preview)**